# post a link from jquery to call a ASHX asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this function:

```
function exportdata(ID) {

   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "export.ashx?ID=" + ID,
          data: "{}",
          /*contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",*/
          dataType: "json"
        }); 
}
```

It works fine but when I open the Developer Tools of Chrome in the Console tab, I see some errors:

```
POST http://localhost:1111/export.ashx?ID=1 undefined (undefined)
POST http://localhost:1111/abc.aspx undefined (undefined)
```

How can I solve this problem?

thanks in dvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be caused by this:

```
data: "{}",
```

When you use braces to send data to `$.ajax`, you do not need quotes around them:

```
data: {},
```

The quotes come in when you want to send data in this fashion:

```
data: "name=John&location=Boston",
```

Also, `data` is not required. If you are not sending any data, simply omit it.

Documentation for jquery ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The parameter coming in is ID and you're using tripID in the code. Could that be it?

Try this

```
function exportdata(tripID) {

   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "export.ashx?ID=" + tripID,
          data: "{}",
          /*contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",*/
          dataType: "json"
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't posting any data and just want to pass a query-string variable you have to use GET:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "export.ashx?ID=" + ID         
    });
```

Comment: Yea, and maybe even easier. `GET` is the default so `type:` could be left off entirely, don't you think?

Comment: It can't be a POST if you are using "GET"?

Comment: Also, is ID defined? Can you alert(ID)?

Comment: Looks like `abc.aspx` is another page. Maybe the calling page, don't know. OP never said what `abc.aspx` was and we don't know what that page is doing.